# How to set an image for TaskbarIcon?

Tags: wpf, exception, taskbar

I downloaded a nuget called `TaskbarNotification`, which contains a class called `TaskbarIcon`.

The next code throws an exception and I don't know how to fix it.
The exception is telling me that the URI is not in the right format.
However, everything works in my app if I do not set the `IconSource` property to anything.

```
var mySource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"..\..\Icons\thumbs-up.jpg", UriKind.Relative));

var icon = new TaskbarIcon();
icon.IconSource = mySource;
```

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the TaskbarIcon from the Hardcodet.Wpf.TaskbarNotification,all I did is create a resource dictionary item;

```
<ResourceDictionary
     xmlns:tb="http://www.hardcodet.net/taskbar">

        <tb:TaskbarIcon
          x:Key="MyNotifyIcon"
          IconSource="/Icons/ico-portail.ico"
          ToolTipText="hello world">

            <tb:TaskbarIcon.TrayToolTip>
                <Border
                  Background="LightBlue"
                  BorderBrush="CadetBlue"
                  BorderThickness="2"
                  CornerRadius="4"
                  Opacity="0.8"
                  Width="160"
                  Height="40">
                    <TextBlock
                        Text="Tooltip of tray-icon"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        />
                </Border>
            </tb:TaskbarIcon.TrayToolTip>
```

And to call if from my piece of code, its as simple as;

```
 tb = (TaskbarIcon)FindResource("MyNotifyIcon");
 tb.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon(@"../../Icons/new.ico");
```

Do not forget to call the reference;

> using Hardcodet.Wpf.TaskbarNotification;

more details on http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36468/WPF-NotifyIcon